# Facing Error while creating a custom recipe to add log level guard

Tags: java, openrewrite

I am trying to create a snippet using Java parser to add a if block.

```java
Expression condition = JavaParser.buildSnippet(
    String.format("if (logger.%sEnabled())", logLevel)
    ).get(0);
```

For the above code, I am getting error in buildSnippet() method, stating its not found. I am using jdk 17 with rewrite-version 6.1.15

I am expecting an alternative for JavaParser.buildSnippet() method

Comment: I don't see any such method in the documentation; maybe I missed it.  Why do you think that exists?

Answer (score 0):

You'll likely want to [look at JavaTemplate instead](https://docs.openrewrite.org/authoring-recipes/modifying-methods-with-javatemplate) of JavaParser. That has an API to actually create the LST elements that you need here.

Comment: I dont have a proper understanding of template that was given in the documentation, can you suggest me in my case, how I. need to proceed.

Comment: Continued here: https://github.com/openrewrite/rewrite-logging-frameworks/issues/111